# What is the best way to remove .mp3 from this list in Python?

Tags: python

So I'm making a bot, and so far I have a command that prints out a directory of all available songs seen here:

```
@bot.command()
async def songs(ctx):
    msg = os.listdir("songs")
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

Which works as expected, it prints the list of songs in that folder.

```
['song1.mp3']
```

However, my main problem here is that it shows the file extension on the end, which I don't want. What would be the best way to go about removing the file extension (.mp3) before printing it?

Comment: Do you only want to remove `.mp3` or also other extensions?

Comment: What's with all the downvotes??

Comment: Askers are encouraged to attempt to work out their issues on their own before asking - and this question shows no evidence of that. That's likely where they are coming from.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `'.mp3'` with `''` as follows:

```
msg = [s.replace('.mp3','') for s in os.listdir("songs")]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple list iteration to remove them would work.

```
[x.rsplit(".", 1)[0] for x in os.listdir("songs")]
```

I have used `rsplit` so that if the filename contains a `.` aside from the file extension, it would be included still. The argument forces a maximum of 1 split - so if the file doesn't have a dot at all it'll still return the full filename.

Note that this will return all files in the directory. If you want to limit it to *just* mp3s, then you could do this;

```
[x.rsplit(".", 1)[0] for x in os.listdir("songs") if x.endswith(".mp3")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need the filenames without the file extensions. So, I encourage you to do this.

```
lst = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in os.listdir("songs")]
```

If you have audio files with different extensions, say, `mp3`, `wav` etc., the above code will handle all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways:

```
msg = [f.split('.')[0] for f in msg]

msg = [f.replace('.mp3', '') for f in msg]
```

Comment: Function `replace` takes 2 arguments.